# Should I immediately eat any cans of meat I find laying around?

Tags: teleglitch

Cans of meat raise your health 10 points, up to a maximum of 150. If my health is < 141 is there any reason to not eat the canned meat as soon as I find it?

Comment: just to clarify "<" means "less than" right? (I'm always confusing them)

Comment: @Ben correct; "<" does in fact mean "less than".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canned meat has a use in a situationally useful crafting recipe, so you may want to keep a can or two around, just in case.

And of course, there are the usual inventory concerns: if you're already carrying four empty cans, but aren't too badly wounded, you may want to hold off eating until you find a use for them.